# Difference between cache clean and cache flush?

Tags: magento2, command-line

I am not satisfied what is difference between below 2 command :

```
1. php bin/magento cache:clean.
2. php bin magento cache:flush.
```

Answer (score 1):

Clean and flush cache types
To purge out-of-date items from the cache, you can clean or flush cache types:

- Cleaning a cache type deletes all items from enabled Commerce cache
  types only. In other words, this option does not affect other
  processes or applications because it cleans only the cache that
  Commerce uses.

  Disabled cache types are not cleaned.

TIP -
Always clean the cache after upgrading versions of Magento Open Source or Adobe Commerce, upgrading from Magento Open Source to Adobe Commerce, or installing B2B for Adobe Commerce or any module.

- Flushing a cache type purges the cache storage, which might affect
  other processes applications that are using the same storage.

Flush cache types if you have already tried cleaning the cache and you are still having issues that you cannot isolate.

You can check the magento doc here.
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/cli/manage-cache.html